# How to create a column in MySQL8 to hold time in 24 hour format

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, sql-insert, create-table

I am trying to INSERT some data into a COLUMN in a MySQL 8 Database.
The table is meant to hold an id for a time slot for each hour of each day of the week. So I have an id per hour (tod) for each day.

It is my own database and I am learning as I go.

I cannot work out how to just add the 24-hour clock part into the column

I am new to this so be gentle

Here is my CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ctg`.`sections` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `day_of_week` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tod` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I am propagating data to the table via a very simple python script

```
    sqlstuff = "INSERT INTO sections(id,day_of_week,tod) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    records = [
        (1,"Sunday",00.00),
        (2,"Sunday",01.00),
        (3,"Sunday",02.00),
        (4,"Sunday",03.00),
        (5,"Sunday",04.00),
        (6,"Sunday",05.00),
        ]

    db.executemany(sqlstuff, records)

    # Ensure we commit the tables
    mydb.commit()

    # Close the database
    db.close()
```

The Python script runs to 168 ID's. Probably a quicker way but I'm not caring at this point.
I have tried tod formatted as '01:00:00' and the above but I keep getting a SQL error stating "Incorrect datetime value.

I have read a lot of the MySQL 8 stuff on time, datetime, timestamp and time_format() but can not work out what I need in my statement to make it insert the 1-hour timeslots I need.

If I need to change the CREATE table statement I can as this is all just on my test setup. I just need some pointers as to what I am blatantly missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the column `tod`'s data type to be [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html).
Also the column `id` can be `AUTO_INCREMENT` so you don't need to supply a value for it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sections` (
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `day_of_week` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tod` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
)ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

To fill the table with 168 rows, 24 for each day of the week, you need 2 recursive `CTE`s.
The 1st will return the days of the week and the 2nd all the hours of the day.
These `CTE`s must be `CROSS` joined to get all the combinations:

```
INSERT INTO sections(day_of_week, tod) 
WITH recursive 
  days AS (
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE date 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date + interval 1 day 
    FROM days
    WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE + interval 6 day 
  ),
  hours AS (
    SELECT '00:00:00' time
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ADDTIME(time, '01:00:00') 
    FROM hours
    WHERE time < '23:00:00' 
  )
SELECT DAYNAME(d.date), h.time
FROM days d CROSS JOIN hours h
ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(d.date), h.time
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ce4265d1db32f41ecc080756132212d).

Comment: Thank you for this. This really helped my understanding and also pointed out I have a lot to learn

Comment: how do i do that. I thought I had

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a time, do not use `DATETIME`, which, as its name indicates, is meant to store a date *and* a time together. Instead, use the `TIME` datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ctg`.`sections` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `day_of_week` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tod` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

Then, pass a proper literal string to the `INSERT` statement:

```
records = [
    (1, 'Sunday', '00:00:00'),
    (2, 'Sunday', '01:00:00'),
    (3, 'Sunday', '02:00:00'),
    (4, 'Sunday', '03:00:00'),
    (5, 'Sunday', '04:00:00'),
    (6, 'Sunday', '05:00:00'),
]
```

It is rather unclear how you will take advantage of this design is. Hours of the week might be better stored as a single `TIME` column (which ranges from  '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'), so it can be used pretty much like an interval.

Comment: and day of week is far better stored as an integer 0-6 or 1-7

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I was looking at the TIME function but i thought it was a timing function so passed it by several times. I will look better next time.